# What is the specifications for a-frame 360 vr video?

Tags: aframe, webvr

I'm using a-frame for a web-vr project, and I'm planning to use 3d environment I made in Cinema 4d. 
But there're not much information about the specification for the video other than the format. 
I already tried to make the resolution same as the sample 360 video(3168x1584) for a-frame, but it also didn't work and I want to know if there's any information about this.

Plz let me know if anyone knows any doc about this. I already tried but I couldn't find any clue yet :'(

Answer (score 0):

use .mp4 format. 
Best if resolution is a power of 2. ie
1024 x 2048 (or any power of 2).

Video textures are known to fail on iphone.

Can you provide a few more details about your project?
How are you viewing it (desktop, phone, platform?)
How is it failing?  No image? errors in console?

I assume you have seen the aframe docs on video textures, but if not here they are.

https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/primitives/a-videosphere.html

https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/material.html#video-textures

Comment: Also, there are ways to test, using event listeners, to get feedback on whether the data from the video source has loaded or not. Here is the basic work flow to make one of these: 1) make a custom component, and attach it to the entity that has the video texture. 2) in the component make a listener (el.addEventListener("materialEventLoadedData", function(evt){ console.log(evt)}    https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/material.html#events